# Buildroot problem with libicudata. What's this?

Tags: buildroot

When I try to build system with buildroot I have problem with makin libicudata.

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/source/data'
/bin/bash ../mkinstalldirs  /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/host-icu-64-2/source/stubdata:/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/host-icu-64-2/source/tools/ctestfw:/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/host-icu-64-2/source/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/host-icu-64-2/source/bin/pkgdata -O ../data/icupkg.inc -q -c -s /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/source/data/out/build/icudt64l -d ../lib -m dll -r 64.2 -e icudt64  -T ./out/tmp -s ./out/build/icudt64l -p icudt64l -L icudata ./out/tmp/icudata.lst -I /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib
pkgdata: cd ../lib/ && /usr/bin/install -c libicudata.so.64.2 /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libicudata.so.64.2
pkgdata: cd /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib && rm -f libicudata.so.64 && ln -s libicudata.so.64.2 libicudata.so.64
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
-- return status = 35584
Error creating symbolic links. Failed command: cd /home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/host/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib && rm -f libicudata.so.64 && ln -s libicudata.so.64.2 libicudata.so.64
Makefile:180: recipe for target 'install-local' failed
make[2]: *** [install-local] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/source/data'
Makefile:153: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/source'
package/pkg-generic.mk:278: recipe for target '/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/.stamp_staging_installed' failed
make: *** [/home/ser-builder2/buildroot/output/build/icu-64-2/.stamp_staging_installed] Error 2
```

I don't know what to do with this. I tried to build this on another computer and everything works fine.

Comment: I am having this same issue

Comment: I don't know exactly why this happens, but I figure is a kernel problem (too new). Maybe this will help. On this other computer, I have 4.15.0-147-generic and everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem too and tracked it down to the execution of pkgdata. Somehow LD_LIBRARY_PATH got screwed which causes '/usr/bin/rm' to fail. To solve it, I've modified Makefile.in and removed LD_LIBRARY_PATH=... from the invocation line.

```
diff -r -u a/source/Makefile.in b/source/Makefile.in
--- a/source/Makefile.in        2022-06-02 10:48:31.493046292 +0200
+++ b/source/Makefile.in        2022-06-02 11:25:57.303758900 +0200
@@ -258,7 +258,7 @@
        @(echo 'TOOLBINDIR=$$(cross_buildroot)/bin' ;\
          echo 'TOOLLIBDIR=$$(cross_buildroot)/lib' ;\
          echo "INVOKE=$(LDLIBRARYPATH_ENVVAR)=$(LIBRARY_PATH_PREFIX)"'$$(TOOLLIBDIR):$$(cross_buildroot)/stubdata:$$(cross_buildroot)/tools/ctestfw:$$$$'"$(LDLIBRARYPATH_ENVVAR)" ;\
-         echo "PKGDATA_INVOKE=$(LDLIBRARYPATH_ENVVAR)=$(LIBRARY_PATH_PREFIX)"'$$(cross_buildroot)/stubdata:$$(cross_buildroot)/tools/ctestfw:$$(TOOLLIBDIR):$$$$'"$(LDLIBRARYPATH_ENVVAR) " ;\
+         echo "PKGDATA_INVOKE= " ;\
          echo ) >> $@
 
 config/icucross.inc: $(top_builddir)/icudefs.mk  $(top_builddir)/Makefile @platform_make_fragment@
```

I know that this question is quite old now, but I want to mention it if someone else will run into this.

Comment: Now that I switched to branch 2022.05.x, I realized that this issue seems to be fixed, meanwhile.